# How can I get all rows where the value of a column's (decimal) fractional-part is > 0?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a very large table in a SQL server DB and I want to get all the rows where the value of a decimal column has a fractional part > 0

For example I have two rows:

```
"John Smith", 123.00
"Mary", 123.05
```

My query should only return  `"Mary", 123.05` so in other words it should return 
all rows that look like this X.0000....1 up to X.9999999999...

I need this to see if I actually need to have my column as a decimal.

Comment: Just a remark: This only works reliably when using a precise data type (DECIMAL), whereas approximate data types (FLOAT, DOUBLE) might report decimals where there are none and vice versa. But, well, FLOAT and DOUBLE are rarely used in a database anyway.

Comment: Besides `FLOOR` you might also try modulo: `WHERE col M%OD 1 <> 0`

Answer (score 2):

You can use modulo for this.

--EDIT--

Removed incorrect statements about SARGability of this approach.

```
declare @Something table
(
    SomeName varchar(20),
    SomeValue numeric(9,2)
)

insert @Something
select 'John Smith', 123.00 union all
select 'Mary', 123.05 

select *
from @Something
where SomeValue % 1 > 0
```

Comment: SARGable? Is `modulo` no function`? And which index to use?

Comment: Slight note - this won't work if the datatype is a `FLOAT`.  `FLOAT` (and `INT`, but `INT` is irrelevant in this context) are incompatible with the `modulo` operator.

Comment: @dnoeth perhaps you are correct it would still be nonSARGable but modulo is certainly not a function, it is an expression.

Comment: @SeanLange . . . `%` is not SARGable.  Neither are expressions such as `+ 0` and `* 1` (unless the optimizer removes them before testing for index compatibility).

Comment: `%` is an operator. `x % y` is an expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using `FLOOR()`.  If the number itself is greater than its `FLOOR`ed value, it must have a decimal.

```
Select  Name, Number
From    Table
Where   Number > Floor(Number)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
WHERE my_column > FLOOR(my_column)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ROUND` function in your WHERE clause.

```
SELECT name, number
FROM yourtable
WHERE (ROUND(number,0)-number) != 0
```

Output:

SQL Fiddle: